# firebase push-messages localization

Tags: android, localization, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Google suggests to use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) instead GCM. It's ok. Accepted.

In the foreground I can implement `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived` and show 'custom' notification with localized message.

But how to implement localization of user notification messages, when application is in the background or **wake-off**?

[This topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876257/push-notification-works-incorrect-when-app-is-on-background-or-not-running/37876727#37876727) suggests:

> Looks like you want to be handling the FCM messages yourself so you can customize the notification a bit more etc, so it would be better to not include the notification key in the POST payload, so all push messages are delivered to your onMessageReceived.

Yes, this resolved problem with `background` state. But when android is in `wake-off` state, no data-only notification received.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876257/push-notification-works-incorrect-when-app-is-on-background-or-not-running/37876727#37876727

Comment: Ok, thanks for the link, but I need some details: does android wake up automatically to process payload (contains only a data)?

Comment: I have checked it. No data-only push notification received in sleep mode. When i wake up android manually - then this notification processed. So, problem is not solved.

Comment: Frank, write right solution or remove duplicate state please.

Comment: I have done this by using only the 'data' key in my application (no 'notification' key). I sent all the data in json format, and onMessageReceived retrieved it by this line of code `remoteMessage.getData().get("key")`.