# How to localize Firebase Cloud Messaging Notifications?

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I am trying to move from OneSignal to Firebase Cloud Messaging. The issue I am having is that I can't define a key value pair in the payload for localizing the notification. I have to define a key-value pair in my strings file in my app. This means the notifications can't be dynamic in that perspective if i want to send a whole different notification that isn't defined in the strings file.

When using OneSignal I could define the payload for localizing like this:

```
{
  'app_id': 'MY_APP_ID',
  'headings': {
               'en': 'The title in English', 
               'de': 'Die Überschrift in Deutsch'
              },

  'contents': {
               'en': 'The body in english', 
               'de': 'Der Inhalt in Deutsch'
              },
}
```

Is this somehow also possible for Cloud Messaging too?

Answer (score 1):

For localizing messages sent to topics, check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844716/4287124).

If you want to localize messages sent to individual devices/tokens I think the only way is to keep track of the ui language of the client associated with the token and do the localization server side before sending the notification.