# GCM message isn't coming in my app, when my app is closed

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-messaging, android-5.0-lollipop

i want to show MY GCM notifications to users when my app is closed or cleared from cache memory, below is my code its working only when app is open but not running in background:

```
public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
    include_once 'dbconfig.php';
    // Set POST variables
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );
```

The smartphone doesn't see any services in my app. Here is a screenshot where you can compare my app with others like whatsapp:
[image]

Below is my Manifest part about GCM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="my.app.path" >    

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
 <!-- ... other permissions -->

<permission
    android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="my.app.path.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    ...>
     <!-- ... activites... -->

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="my.app.path" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>      

    <service
        android:name=".MyGcmListener"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I want to show notifications like whatsApp.

Comment: 1) migrate to FCM 2) read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876257/push-notification-works-incorrect-when-app-is-on-background-or-not-running/37876727#37876727

Comment: whether its not possible without FCM ? i don't know any thing regarding FCM

Comment: check all type of user permission & permission to using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422551/gcm-push-notification-not-revived/38423390#38423390

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if it does help to set the priority to [`high`](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) when sending messages?

Set to `High priority` allowing the GCM service to wake a sleeping device when possible and open a network connection to your app server. Apps with instant messaging, chat, or voice call alerts, for example, generally need to open a network connection and make sure GCM delivers the message to the device without delay. Set high priority only if the message is time-critical and requires the user’s immediate interaction, and beware that setting your messages to high priority contributes more to battery drain compared to normal priority messages.

Comment: I have tried this solution to put  High priority option while sending messages but its not solved my problem