# GCM Push Notification Not Revived

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, gcmlistenerservice

Below you can find  the manifest file, is their anything wrong with configuration of GCM push notification classes ?

**no notification is received at all on android devices but apple devices receive the notification**

```
 package="ac.iec"
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission
    android:name="ac.iec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="ac.iec.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <category android:name="ac.iec"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
           <service
        android:name=".pushnotification.GCMIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".pushnotification.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Comment: Use FCM which is very easy to use. check this link https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have miss some `user permisssion` & `reciver` set like this way.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

this permission to set

```
<permission
    android:name="your package name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

this user permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="your package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

this code set in `application` side.

```
 <!-- GCM Receiver -->
   <!-- this package name set your broadcast receiver class -->
    <receiver

        android:name="package name .GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="main package name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

try this code in your manifest file.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`<receiver>` tag and `<services>` tag should be in `<application>` tag.

Or if you support pre-4.4, REGISTRATION action should be added.
https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client

> If you want to support pre-4.4 KitKat devices, add the following
>   action to the intent filter declaration for the receiver: