# Broadcast Receiver not working when app is not running

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

My broadcast receiver does not work when the application is not running in the background.

### Tried with different intent filters

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

    <receiver android:name=".network.NetworkChangeReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".view.activity.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".view.activity.BarLoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

My receiver works fine when the app is running in the background but as soon as I remove my recent apps it does not work.
Running on API 19

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257310/android-keep-broadcastreceiver-in-background

Comment: your phone is Android N?

Comment: @M.Ron refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422551/gcm-push-notification-not-revived/38423390#38423390

Comment: Note that if a user "force stop" your application, then everything goes off, including receiving any broadcast (even local), services, activities, etc. As far as application goes, nothing can be done, until your application is "launched" again.

Comment: @Bonatti Does that include swiping from recents?

Comment: No. It is from "Config -> Applications -> YOUR_APP -> Force Stop", or any "Application Manager" that the user can have installed (usually on a rooted device), that can programatically stop other applications... Edit your question, and add as much information as you have, such as Logcats, the device model/manufacturer, the Android version, build number, etc.

Comment: Just to make sure we're all clear - "does not work" as in "isn't called" or as in "doesn't do what I expect?"

Comment: @Bonatti I am unable to run by tasks in the broadcast receiver even if I clear my clear my recent applications

Comment: Post your entire AndroidManifest. This is likely a permission issue (EACESS on your LogCat?). Probably you didnt request permissions to observe Network state changes. And again, read the last comment. Post any and all relevant information you may have. These can help us, help you. Logcat, Android version, device manufacturer, etc.

Comment: @Bonatti It works well when I run the app and change my network ,But not able to when the app is not running    ---> I am using this  as permissions android.permission.INTERNET and android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

Comment: @LucasPaolillo Its Lollipop

Comment: Since you never added the relevant information, we can safely guess that you are not requesting runtime permissions. Set your API level to 19 (Kitkat, before most the security changes started, and run in "legacy mode") and check if the issue continues. And again, POST any and ALL relevant info, into your question. Press the edit button, and writte it down

Comment: I even tried API 19 and above @Bonatti

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it worked in other android phones.
as broadcast receivers and services are by default not allowed in Xiaomi phones

Answer (score 1):

I would try putting a android:process=":remote" in the Manifest definition of the receiver so that it will run on a separate task.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't seen your entire `AndroidManifest` but my first suspect is that you're lacking the proper permission.
In order to listen to network changes you must declare that you are using this permission in the manifest like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

the next suspect is the name you gave, maybe try giving the full path to the reciever name

Comment: android.permission.INTERNET android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE --> I have added these as my persmissions

Comment: you can also try explicitly stating that the service is exported with `androi:exported="true"`