# GcmListenerService is not called while application stopped. Android GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-service

My manifest file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

 <application
    android:name="com.example.app"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"

...activities..

 <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.example.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

  <service
        android:name=".GCMPushReceiverService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

 <!--             GCM Registration Intent Service -->
    <service
        android:name=".GCMRegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
   </application>
```

Where `GcmBroadcastReceiver extends GcmReceiver` and `GCMPushReceiverService extends GcmListenerService`. No methods inside either of this class is triggered when the application is stopped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notification works incorrect when app is on background or not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876257/push-notification-works-incorrect-when-app-is-on-background-or-not-running)

Comment: **No methods inside either of this class is triggered when the application is stopped.** what do you mean by this??

Comment: while receiving a notification when app is in background onMessageReceived() inside GCMPushReceiverService is triggered. But when the app is stoped, nothing happens.

Comment: @Tim Not duplicate coz i am using gcm not fcm

Comment: @HariKrishnan they are basically the same

Comment: basically, not exactly. I need solution for gcm not for fcm.

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422551/gcm-push-notification-not-revived/38423390#38423390