# I can not receive message from GCM connect server when my app is not active

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

It runs normally when I test Google Cloud Message samples provided by Google.But I can not receive message from GCM connect server when my app is  not active.I have check all I should do but the problem is still with me.
Is there anyone has the same question?Please give some effective solution

Comment: How do you send messages?

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed not all questions are about debugging code

Comment: @TimCastelijns I send message via Postman with the Message format like this:{ 
  "notification" : {
    "body" : "beautiful match13!",
    "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark2"
    },
  "to" : "/topics/gcm123"
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notification works incorrect when app is on background or not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876257/push-notification-works-incorrect-when-app-is-on-background-or-not-running)

Comment: The link I gave talks about fcm, but it is the same for gcm

Comment: @TimCastelijns I hava test the solution but it didn't work.Should I install my app from Google Play?