# Open specific Activity when notification clicked in FCM

Tags: android, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am working on App in which I am required to show notification.
For notification, i am using FireBase Cloud Messaging **(FCM)**. 
I am able to get Notification when app is in background.

But when I click on notification, it redirect to **home.java** page. I want it to redirect to **Notification.java** page.

So,please tell me how to specify Activity in on Click of notification.
I am using two services:

1.)**MyFirebaseMessagingService**

2.)**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService**

This is my code sample for **onMessageReceived()** method in MyFirebaseMessagingService class.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
Bitmap bitmap;


public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {



    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */

private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    intent.putExtra("Notification", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
            .setContentTitle(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
             .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

/*
*To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
* */
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: remove "notification" from your fcm payload and it will work

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Comment: You mean to say, remove getNotification() from getNotification().getBody();??

Comment: no not at all. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37876727/1843331

Comment: Sir! I am receiving notification corrcetly, no problem in that!! I want to open activity Notification.java when we click on received notification. How to specify this in code.

Comment: check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413178/6166726 it will solve your question

Comment: @ArmanReyaz : do you reach any conclusion to find the answer , i am suffering from same issue

Answer (score 51):

**With FCM, you can send two [types of messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)  to clients:**

**1. Notification messages:** sometimes thought of as "display messages."

FCM automatically displays the message to end-user devices on behalf of the client app. Notification messages have a predefined set of user-visible keys.

**2. Data messages:** which are handled by the client app.

Client app is responsible for processing data messages. Data messages have only custom key-value pairs.

According to FCM document [Receive Messages in an Android App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

> - **Notifications delivered when your app is in the background.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. 
>     A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
> - **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and foreground.** In this case, the notification is delivered to the
>     device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras 
>     of the intent of your launcher Activity.

**Set `click_action` in the notification payload:**

So, if you want to process the messages arrived in the background, you have to send `click_action` with message.

`click_action` is a [parameter of the notification payload](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support)

If you want to open your app and perform a specific action, set `click_action` in the notification payload and map it to an intent filter in the Activity you want to launch.

For example, set `click_action` to `OPEN_ACTIVITY_1` to trigger an intent filter like the following:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

FCM payload looks like below:

```
{
  "to":"some_device_token",
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
      "title": "hello",
      "body": "test message",
      "click_action": "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
  },
  "data": {
      "extra":"juice"
  }
}
```

Comment: This "click_action: key works for data messages too, when the app is in background.

Comment: @ManishJoshi No, it works only for notification message. But you can set pending intent into notification using data message, to open specific activity when user click on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62446449/fcm-data-message-is-not-navigating-to-desired-fragment-when-app-is-in-background I was facing this issue and to resolve it I added the click_action key to my payload to resolve it

Answer (score 12):

When app is in background, Intent must be delivered at your launcher activity . So it opens your Launcher activity. Now you check if there is data in Intent in launcher activity then start your required Activity.

**Inside your Launcher Activity**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

if (extras != null) {
  // possible launched from notification
  // check if desired notification data present in extras then its 
  // confirmed that launched from notification
  
  }else{
   // not launched from notification
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example? How do you check if there is data in intent in the launcher activity.

Answer (score 9):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.yourapplication_YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

---

**Your FirebaseMessagingService.java file onMessageReceived method:**

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
    String title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String message=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String click_action=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    Intent intent=new Intent(click_action);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(message);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

---

**Your cloud function/server code for notification must be like this:**

```
    notification: {
        title: "TITLE OF NOTIFICATION",
        body: "NOTIFICATION MESSAGE",
        sound: "default",
        click_action:"com.example.yourapplication_YOUR_NOTIFICATION_NAME"
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the easiest way to understand this.

When you send a data payload with the notification payload as

```
 notification: {
            title: "Your order status.",
            body: orderStatusDetail,
            clickAction: "ShopFragment"
        },
        data: {
            ORDER_ID: orderId
        }
```

The notification clickAction will be the filter you will use to pass data into your Activity, what data? The data sent by the `data: { }` object appended to the payload.

So, the clickAction will trigger the intent filter in your Manifest, so first we need to create it

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ShopFragment"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
```

Now we set the intent filter with the same name as our clickAction, doing this we trigger that whenever we press the notification at our notification tab, this intent filter will launch and so on the activity associated with this intent filter.

And then, just use `intent.getStringExtra("ORDER_ID")` at your MainActivity to get your String extra sent at your data payload.

Make sure that **ORDER_ID** in this case is the key we send from the `data { }` object and needs to be the same in the client to get this data.

Answer (score 2):

Open **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java** file

inside that file there is a **sendNotification()** method, there you have to specify your activity you need to navigate to in the Intent as shown below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivityName.class);
```

if you are sending multiple notification and you want to navigate to different Activities on click of a particular Notification you can use any conditional statement to achieve it, my suggestion is to use a **switch case** as shown below

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    switch(condition) {
       case '1': intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOne.class);
                 break;
       case '2': intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
                 break;
       case '3': intent = new Intent(this, ActivityThree.class);
                 break;
       default : intent = new Intent(this, DefaultActivity.class);
                 break;
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    intent.putExtra("Notification", TrueOrFalse);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
```

Using this logic you can open a specific activity on Notification click in FCM.
This works perfectly for me.
Thanks

Comment: this always opening the launcher activity.