# open specific activity when e push notifications from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have android application and tried to receive a push notifications.
My problem when click the reserved notification open the main activity, 
I need when received push notifications from firebase open a specific activity directly. This is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo_a)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            handleDataMessage(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Mo", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_Page.class);
        startActivity(resultIntent);
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {

        if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
            // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
            Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
            pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
            NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
            notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_Page.class);
            startActivity(resultIntent);
        } else {
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notification_Page.class);
            startActivity(resultIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: check this one  .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718155/open-specific-activity-when-notification-clicked-in-fcm

Comment: Are you trying to start the activity when you receive the push notification or when the user "clicks" the notification in the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a pending intent in to your notification. So first create a pending intent:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Destination.class), 0);
```

Then add to your `NotificationBuilder`, where you define the title, description, etc.. of the notification, the following parameter:

```
builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
```

**UPDATE:**

You have your `NotificationCompatBuilder` already in your code.

Replace this:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo_a)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
```

with this:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Destination.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo_a)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

Comment: where ?? add this ?!!

Comment: @MoayedAlayseh Oops.. a typo error. I fixed it. Can you try again?

Comment: @MoayedAlayseh Do you have set your destination activity?

Comment: PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, Notification_Page.class), 0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo_a)
                .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
                .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());

Comment: this is my code and when click into notification the app open to the first activity !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using `PendingIntent` to be able to start a specific activity when clicking on the notification. Add this to your code

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, YOUT_REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
```

You can change your code to this even though you are not implmented the `handleDataMessage` well but this will allow you to start an activity when clicking on the notification

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));

    //two lines addded
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_logo_a)
            .setContentTitle(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"))
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody())
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);//added line
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        handleDataMessage(json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Mo", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {

    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {
        // app is in foreground, broadcast the push message
        Intent pushNotification = new Intent(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(pushNotification);
        NotificationUtils notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(getApplicationContext());
        notificationUtils.playNotificationSound();

    }
}
```

Comment: where ?? add this ?!!