# Can't start Application to particular activity on Notification click from FCM

Tags: android, firebase

I'm experiencing this problem: If I click on the notification and my app is closed, `HomeActivity` is opened instead of the requested one.

I'm raising the notification like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ArticleActivity_.class);
intent.putExtra(ArticleActivity.KEY_ARTICLE_ID, articleId);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0 , intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(notification.getTitle())
            .setContentText(notification.getBody())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

Notification n = notificationBuilder.build();
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0 , n);
```

And everything works fine if the application is opened. But if I close it, after clicking on the notification, `HomeActivity` will be opened instead of the one I configured.

Comment: You mean like you want different activity to open in different notification click?

Comment: I mean I want to open some particular activity different from HomeActivity.

Comment: is that from firebase?

Comment: yes, I'm getting a notification from FCM and pushing it, on users click im going to open concrete Activity

Comment: There are different type of push in FCM so you can do this with launcher activity in manifest and handle bundle accordingly is the way

Comment: Data push ,Notifictaion Push

Comment: Could you please provide me some link to understand this ?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718155/open-specific-activity-when-notification-clicked-in-fcm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having this problem because that is how FCM works. There are 2 types of push notifications. The first type is "notification" and the second type is "data". Both can be visualize as a JSON payload:

```
"notification": {
    //key values
}

"data": {
    //your custom key values
}
```

There is a third type which is a combination of both.

The "notification" type will create a default visual notification with default behavior when the app is not in the foreground. And it will execute whatever your write inside `onMessageReceived` when the app is open. The second type "data" will always do what you code inside `onMessageReceived`.

From the Firebase web console, you can send "notification" type or the combined type. For sending only "data" you need to send it from Firebase Functions or from a Server (that complies with the FCM requisites).

**There is a trick you can do to get your goal**. Combined payload, that can be send from the Firebase web console, contains "notification" and "data". The "data" key-values are available after the user click the notification. That information is available as extra data from the intent opening the default launcher Activity, so there you can change your Activity.

In your launcher Activity, add the following:

```
String notification = getIntent().getStringExtra("your-key");
if (notification != null) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
}
```

This way you can validate that the Activity is being opened because the default notification was clicked, and is always a String because payload in push FCM must be by rule always String. In other cases, if the user simply opened the app, then the String will be null, and you don't *redirect* the user.