# How does Firebase Cloud Messaging work on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I am sending data to FCM server via an 'admin app' and would like the other 'non-admin app' to be able to receive push notifications, whenever the 'admin app' sends data to the FCM server.

To achieve that, I am using AWS SNS in tandem with FCM to store the list of recipients and to disseminate the push notifications. However, as opposed to the answer stated in **https://stackoverflow.com/a/47413178/9846004**, when the application is in the foreground, my device *does not receive any push notifications*; it only receives them when it is in the background.

In addition, how do I implement the feature to "**open up the intended activity screen**" using the "**click_action**" key in the payload? Do I need to include the full package name as part of the value?

Something like {"click_action" : "com.example.application.androidapp.main_activity"} or just {"click_action" : "main_activity"} will do?

Comment: click_action is an intent filter string, not the name of an activity.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Thanks for the response. May I clarify if you are referring to the **action name:** attribute in "Manifest.xml"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive messages while your app is in foreground, create a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and override the `onMessageReceived` and `onDeletedMessages` methods. For more information, visit [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) link.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase) can help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I have overridden that "OnMessageReceived" method already. The problem now is that I dont even see the program executing that part of the code while attempting to debug.

Comment: I have attached a link the updated answer. Maybe it can help.

Comment: Thank you for the great tips and resource. After countless testings, I have finally managed to get it up and working. Will post my findings as soon as possible.

Comment: @Gohweiyang Great!