# Open specific page in android using Push notification

Tags: android

I am building an android app having a Login, FrontPage and Prompt pages.

Following some online tutorials, I added a push notification to the app. But when using the notification, the Login page (being the first) pops up everytime. I need the push notification to open the Prompt page. How can I do this?

I am using Android studio and Google Firebase for the push notification.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40718155/open-specific-activity-when-notification-clicked-in-fcm

Comment: I understand but how do i edit the FCM code or particularly the set click_action for google firebase?