# Xamarin Android FCM localization

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

How I can do localization with FCM on Xamarin.Android? I successfully implemented localization on iOS platform by creating folders with language codes and put in these folders "string.xml" files.
But I tried do it on android but unsuccessfully. 
Can you give link to sample or just explain how i can implement it?

Also I tried create my realization for this task. It's works but when app is minimized or closed this code doesn't work.

```
[Service]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
    {
        const string TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
        public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification()?.Body);
            SendNotification(message);
        }

        public void SendNotification(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

            string contentText = null;
            if (message.Data.Any())
            {
                int resourceId;
                try
                {
                    resourceId = Resources.GetIdentifier(message.Data.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "body_loc_key").Value,
                        "string", PackageName);
                }
                catch (Java.Lang.NullPointerException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Exception in SendNotification: {ex.StackTrace}");
                    return;
                }

                var list = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(message.Data.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Key == "body_loc_args").Value);
                var pattern = Resources.GetText(resourceId);
                try
                {
                    contentText = string.Format(pattern, list.ToArray());
                }
                catch (System.FormatException ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.InnerException);
                }
            }
            var notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.spirallogo)
                .SetContentTitle("Custom Title")
                .SetContentText(contentText ?? message.GetNotification()?.Body)
                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                .SetShowWhen(true)
                .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(this);
            notificationManager.Notify(0, notificationBuilder.Build());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem by changing payload. Me help this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876727/7429947

Just I change my payload to FCM and then push got in my handler (OnMessageReceived method).

Idle:

```
{
 "registration_ids": ["..."],
 "data": {
    "body_loc_key": "new_chatmessage",
    "body_loc_args": ["mark","Yo!"]
 },
 "notification": {
    "body":"",
    "title":""
 }
}
```

Working:

```
{
  "registration_ids": ["..."],
  "data": {
    "body_loc_key": "new_chatmessage",
    "body_loc_args": ["mark","Yo!"]
   }
}
```