# Android Firebase Push Notification with image from server(php) not showing image in notification while app in background

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implemented android firebase push notificaiton with image using php(server). Notification with image working perfectly while app in foreground. But while app in background only notification received with title and message but image not displaying. I am sending everything as data only. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
`     
**PHP CODE**
<?php

define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxx' );


 $message = array
      (
    'message'   => "$body",
    'title' => "notification",
    'image'=> $image_url,
    'vibrate'=>1,




      );
$fields = array
        (
            'registration_ids'      => $regid,
            'data'  => $message,


        );


$headers = array
        (
            'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
    $result = curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;

}
```

**MYFIREBASE MESSAGING SERVICE**

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMService";
Bitmap bitmap;

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    // There are two types of messages data messages and notification messages. Data messages are handled
    // here in onMessageReceived whether the app is in the foreground or background. Data messages are the type
    // traditionally used with GCM. Notification messages are only received here in onMessageReceived when the app
    // is in the foreground. When the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed.
    // When the user taps on the notification they are returned to the app. Messages containing both notification
    // and data payloads are treated as notification messages. The Firebase console always sends notification
    // messages. For more see: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options
    //
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //The message which i send will have keys named [message, image, AnotherActivity] and corresponding values.
    //You can change as per the requirement.

    //message will contain the Push Message
    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
    String tittle = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
    //imageUri will contain URL of the image to be displayed with Notification
    String imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as True then when the user taps on notification, in the app AnotherActivity will be opened.
    //If the key AnotherActivity has  value as False then when the user taps on notification, in the app MainActivity will be opened.


    //To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);

    sendNotification(tittle,message, bitmap);

}


/**
 * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
 */

private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody, Bitmap image) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, home.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);




    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            /*Notification icon image*/
            .setLargeIcon(image)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.shoppingcart)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                    .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}

/*
 *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
 * */
public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return bitmap;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    }
}
```

`

Comment: please post your code were you receive notification.

Comment: @VadimEksler I posted my code .  My problem is Iam receiving  notification with image in foreground .. but in background only title and message displaying as notification but image not displaying. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is power saving mode enable on your device? I've had a situation like this before that it was the cause of the problem.

Comment: @NoBody Power saving mode is already disabled state in my device

Comment: @sundar did you find the solution for the problem??

Comment: Please see this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876727/3037523

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom view with below code to load image.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
            if (remoteMessage.getData().get(IMAGE_URL) != null) {
                final NotificationTarget notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(getApplicationContext(), largeRemoteViews, R.id.notification_image, notification, 0);
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(remoteMessage.getData().get(IMAGE_URL)).asBitmap().into(notificationTarget);
                    }
                });
            }
```